# Is this normal kitten behaviour?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, junior-pets, new-pets

I adopted a 11 week male from the shelter. I've never had a cat this young and some behaviour I'm not sure if it's normal for clumsy cats or there's something wrong.

- Every night he is suckling on my hand, I try to transfer him to a blanket or soft toy, but he always comes back to my hand.
- When jumping up a cat tree, couch, bed, table he missed A LOT and then falls, but he always gets up and tries again, but sometimes he falls 4 times in a row. He's never limped or cried in pain, he just carries on, but is it normal for kittens to not know how to climb or hold on?
- He's very clumsy, he isn't specially aware and just plumps himself down anywhere even if it's the edge of leg, bed, couch and then proceeds to fall again.
- He doesn't wiggle his butt when attacking.

Is this all normal, or should I be worried?

Comment: No, that's not normal. Take the kitten to the vet as soon as possible.

Comment: Okay,  i will. May i ask which behaviour is bad or all?

Comment: @Kitty.kat The clumsiness is what concerns me. How long have you had him?

Comment: 4 days so far. He's from a shelter.

Comment: Agree, it's the clumsiness that worries me. The nursing is probably just a habit, and can be discouraged over time. Not wiggling his butt before pouncing is perfectly normal as not all cats do that.

Comment: Ok, I will go to the vet today again because he has the flu and the medication isn't helping so i will bring up the clumsiness issue

Comment: This is only speculation, as I'm not a vet, but the kitten's flu could be affecting it's ears (sort of like human colds and flues can "clog" your ears). The ears are very important for a cat's stabilization and balance. You may see the kitten regain balance once the flu is treated.

Comment: Thank you :) the vet said that the behaviour I described is completely normal ans as he grows he will be fine or he will grow into a clumsy cat. So idk anymore ‍♀️